# Problem regarding sub-netting and sub-net mask

Tags: networking, subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

An organization is allocated the IP block of 172.16.0.0/16. It has a head office and three branches each of which can have 500 to 4000 hosts. You are required to subnet their IP block and suggest suitable subnets for each location.

> 1) How many subnet bits should be used? **For what ?**

---

> 2) How many usable hosts can be there in each subnet? **That depends on the answer to for what above**

---

> 3) Assign a suitable subnet for each of the following locations **which locations?**

---

> 4) Write the subnet mask of the above subnets in dotted decimal format. **which subnets?**

please can someone explain procedure of calculating above things.

Comment: Off topic. Also sounds like homework and, if it is, tag it as such.

Comment: Actually I'm learning sub-netting and I got some questions regarding that so I need to check whether my answers are correct or not that's why I put this in Stack-overflow.

Comment: As it is homework you don't get an answer from me. Homework is for exercise and not that others do it for you. But if you need to cheat then search for an online subnet calculator. This is at least half the way.

Comment: Read the question *carefully* it cannot be answered as it is incomplete.

Comment: @pst: No, meta tags are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer

1) we have to use 2 bits to represents the network

---

3) So three sub-nets will be

- 172.16.0.192/18
- 172.16.0.128/18
- 172.16.0.64/18

---

4) Subnet mask will be

- 172.16.0.192/18 -:255.255.255.192
- 172.16.0.128/18 -:255.255.255.128
- 172.16.0.64/18  -:255.255.255.64